# WIndows App Navigation Issue Using Cordova and Visual Studio

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, windows

I have successfully created xap file for my windows application using cordova.
I have deployed cordova app on my windows phone.
App runs fine but giving following error on navigations.

```
You Need to Install an App For This Task.Would You Like to Search One in the Store?
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing this issue. On further investigation found out that hyperlinks with a querystring don't work, they give the above error. Where as links without querystring work perfectly fine.

Way around this is make a call to a function and then navigate.

example:
HTML

```
<a onclick="openURL(7)">Click me</a>
```

JS

```
function openURL(id) { 
    window.location.href = '/destinationURL/'+id;
}
```

Comment: i have also investigated on this & found this solution http://www.stephenpauladams.com/articles/angularjs-cordova-windows-phone-quirk/